# SSH doesn't run commands following sudo

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to execute multiple commands on a remote server. The issue I'm having is that after the `sudo` command is ran, the ssh connection gets closed automatically.

The main test that is failing:

```sh
ssh -i "/path/to/key/id_rsa" user@server << EOF
sudo ls -la "/etc/redhat-release"
cat "/etc/redhat-release"
EOF
```

Returns only the `ls` result

```sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55 Jan 29  2013 /etc/redhat-release
```

While if I put both commands on the same line, i.e.

```sh
ssh -i "/path/to/key/id_rsa" user@server << EOF
sudo ls -la "/etc/redhat-release"; cat "/etc/redhat-release"
EOF
```

I will get the result of both commands

```sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55 Jan 29  2013 /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

Now for the weirdest part:

- the main test **does** work on an other server with identical configuration. There are sets of servers where it works, and other sets where it doesn't.
- if I remove the `sudo` from the test, I will get the result from both commands, so it's not an `ssh` limitation

e.g.

```sh
ssh -i "/path/to/key/id_rsa" user@server << EOF
ls -la "/etc/redhat-release"
cat "/etc/redhat-release"
EOF

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55 Jan 29  2013 /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

Additional information:

- Both commands have the `NOPASSWD` flag in the `sudoers` file so no password is asked.
- `requiretty` is commented out.
- ssh version: `OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010`
- SELinux is disabled
- the `ssh -vvv` option doesn't show any significant difference in the logs between a working and non-working server
- `sshd_config` are the same between a working and non-working server

I'm assuming here that there must be some configuration difference between the sets of servers because they are consistent with each-other, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Try `sudo ls -la "/etc/redhat-release" < /dev/null`. The sudo command may somehow be invoking something that reads from stdin.

Comment: Oh wow, that partly solved my issue. Adding this I got  the two result, but now how can I "fix" the server so that `sudo` doesn't expect an input? The `requiretty` and `nopasswd` are set properly.

Comment: You have to figure out why something is reading from stdin during the sudo call. It might not be the sudo program per se; for example it might be something in the .bashrc of the user who you're sudoing to.

Comment: Personally I'm not a fan of running sudo inside ssh. It'd be simpler to set up an ssh key that lets you connect as root while limiting you to running whatever command you need to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `sudo` version (`sudo -V`).

Turns out one server was running `Sudo version 1.8.6p3` while the other was on `Sudo version 1.8.21p2` and a was running in a bug which was fixed in [sudo 1.8.20](https://www.sudo.ws/stable.html#1.8.20):

> Fixed an issue where sudo would consume stdin if it was not connected to a tty even if log_input is not enabled in sudoers. [Bug #786](https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=786).

Updating the `sudo` version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround:

```
ssh -i "/path/to/key/id_rsa" user@server sudo bash << EOF
ls -la "/etc/redhat-release"
cat "/etc/redhat-release"
EOF
```

Comment: The thing is, the service account doesn't have access to do `sudo bash`. The post is a simplification of a bigger application where some code runs multiple commands in succession and after it runs a `sudo` command the connexion gets closed and the code will fail the next time it tries to write to the channel.